# Reading GeoJSON file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, geojson

This is my GeoJSON file

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "maps",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
    { "IDLo": "1", "SoHieu": "1-1", "KyHieu": "C", "TenLo": "C1-1", "TenCty": "CMC Data Center"}, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 106.791800519464871, 10.854928689692501 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792069337729856, 10.855930098557222 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792653322236532, 10.855766231881775 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79231961680415, 10.854783029941672 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791800519464871, 10.854928689692501 ] ] ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
    { "IDLo": "2", "SoHieu": "1-2", "KyHieu": "C", "TenLo": "C1-2", "TenCty": "ASCENDAS" }, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 106.79264868743887, 10.855779887550094 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792064702932166, 10.855943754285464 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791786615071828, 10.854942345054598 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79101723865827, 10.855151730898562 ], 
                                                        [ 106.790461062937595, 10.855306494254153 ], 
                                                        [ 106.789969774384346, 10.855424842648457 ], 
                                                        [ 106.789478485831097, 10.855688850436046 ], 
                                                        [ 106.78819928167357, 10.857819111634392 ], 
                                                        [ 106.790915273109462, 10.859412245764197 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791907119811313, 10.857746282442497 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792111050908886, 10.857518691103408 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792379869173871, 10.857291099590915 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792583800271444, 10.856999782201919 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792732113796944, 10.856544598212894 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792741383392297, 10.856116724630859 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79264868743887, 10.855779887550094 ] ] ] } }

]}
```

How can I access to `"TenCty": "CMC Data Center"` to change the value in javascript?

For example, I want to change `CMC Data Center` into something that users input.

Comment: You can use php. View this question [How to update/edit a JSON file using PHP \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806224/how-to-update-edit-a-json-file-using-php)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What have you done so far? where do you want to change the value? This question in its current state is not easy to answer. This probably is a better fit for stackoverflow, but in its current state might be a difficult answer even there.

Comment: If you're in a Node.js environment, read the geojson file as you would any other json file. ie: `const fs = require('fs'); const data = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('./data.geojson', 'utf8') );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to store it in a database, serve it as a WFS with [GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/index.html), and then have a method of interfacing with the database via PHP or some other backend system, but a quick and dirty way of doing it is to just make it a variable:

```
var myGeoJSON = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "maps",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
    { "IDLo": "1", "SoHieu": "1-1", "KyHieu": "C", "TenLo": "C1-1", "TenCty": "CMC Data Center"}, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 106.791800519464871, 10.854928689692501 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792069337729856, 10.855930098557222 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792653322236532, 10.855766231881775 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79231961680415, 10.854783029941672 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791800519464871, 10.854928689692501 ] ] ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
    { "IDLo": "2", "SoHieu": "1-2", "KyHieu": "C", "TenLo": "C1-2", "TenCty": "ASCENDAS" }, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 106.79264868743887, 10.855779887550094 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792064702932166, 10.855943754285464 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791786615071828, 10.854942345054598 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79101723865827, 10.855151730898562 ], 
                                                        [ 106.790461062937595, 10.855306494254153 ], 
                                                        [ 106.789969774384346, 10.855424842648457 ], 
                                                        [ 106.789478485831097, 10.855688850436046 ], 
                                                        [ 106.78819928167357, 10.857819111634392 ], 
                                                        [ 106.790915273109462, 10.859412245764197 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791907119811313, 10.857746282442497 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792111050908886, 10.857518691103408 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792379869173871, 10.857291099590915 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792583800271444, 10.856999782201919 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792732113796944, 10.856544598212894 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792741383392297, 10.856116724630859 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79264868743887, 10.855779887550094 ] ] ] } }

]}
```

Now you can just treat it like a regular javascript object:

```
myGeoJSON.features[0].properties.TenCity = "changed value"
```

Note that this is only feasible for small JSON objects (I would not recommend doing this for anything larger than a few MB)